# How to access REST APIs hosted locally on Alexa

Tags: rest, web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a custom Alexa Skill and have a requirement where I want Alexa to access REST APIs that are hosted locally on http://localhost:8080? Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you already try ngrok?
ngrok can make your locally hosted application available to internet in just a few steps.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this, and I’m assuming you are hosting the skill on AWS Lambda, it would involve quite a bit of work.

Your local endpoints need to be accessible from outside of your network, which requires port forwarding in your router to your machine where the endpoints are hosted. This needs to be configured in your router.

An easier way is to deploy your project containing the API to something like Heroku, which can be done easily. They give you a domain and make the endpoints accessible to Lambda. This should be possible within their free tier.

Comment: thanks! My local application is hosted and configured for WildFly(Jboss) and uses PostgreSQL as a database. Will hosting on Heroku require changes to these parameters?

Comment: @Sambhav I’m not that familiar there, but I am sure they got you covered, they have tons of setups.

Comment: @Sambhav consider hosting your application on AWS. You can set up API Gateway to receive the requests and forward to a Lambda or EC2 endpoint where your application resides.

Answer (score 1):

Here' a [link](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-a-public-ip-address-2625974) to a pretty good article about how IP addresses work.

Allowing a device sitting on your local network (eg. a laptop computer or Raspberry Pi connected to your wifi) to be accessed from outside your local network (eg. from a service running on AWS) will involve mapping 2 separate IP addresses:

1. The IP address assigned to your router (your public IP)
2. The private IP addresses assigned by your router to your devices (laptop, iPhone, RPi, etc).

You have a couple options for allowing your router's IP (#1) to be accessible from outside your local network:

a. Pay your internet provider to provide you with a static IP address
 b. Use a dynamic DNS service such as [DuckDNS](https://www.duckdns.org) or [No-IP](https://www.noip.com/).

Once you have a fixed public IP that can be used to access your router, you will then need to map a port on your router (#1) to the device IP on your local network (#2). This is usually referred to as "port forwarding". Most routers will support configuring this. In effect, your tell your router "when you get a message to : pass it to my laptop :"

Your local private IP address will typically have an IP value like 192.168.0.23 (where the 23 can be anything from 1 to 254).

An outside IP will start with something other than 192. Refer to the first link above regarding IP ranges.

You can google "port forwarding" and "public IP" for more info on how IP addresses and port forwarding work, but hopefully this will help get you started. It may seem a bit complicated at first, but if I can understand it, then anyone can :-)